# Tab space in Markdown

Tags: syntax, markdown

I want to use one/multiple Tab space in Markdown. I used, "    &nbsp", which is working. But if i want to use multiple Tab space, then MarkDown Document will not look good.

I wanted to use like this below,

```
Main Topic
*Tabspace* Subtopic1
*Tabspace**Tabspace* Some Points for subtopic1
*Tabspace* Subtopic2
*Tabspace**Tabspace* Some Points for subtopic2
```

Actual look should be

```
Main Topic
    Subtopic1
        Some Points for subtopic1
     Subtopic2
        Some Points for subtopic2
```

Any other alternative for &nbsp

Answer (score 71):

This can be helpful

- Type `nbsp` to add a single space.
- Type `ensp` to add 2 spaces.
- Type `emsp` to add 4 spaces.
- You can use non-breaking space (`nbsp`) 4 times to insert a tab.

Please append `&` in the beginning and `;` in the end of the above suggested space syntax

Comment: So you can make an inline tab `&emsp;` like this.

Answer (score 34):

## Use non-breaking spaces

In Markdown, as any markup languages, the tab space collapses to a single space.
Also, several consecutive horizontal whitespace (e.g. spaces, tabs) collapse to a single space or they are removed from the beginning of a paragraph.

**Instead of a tab space you must use several non-breaking spaces:**
*"a space character that prevents consecutive whitespace characters from collapsing into a single space, and also prevents an automatic line break at its position"*.

#### Example

This line uses     non-breaking     spaces in many places; they    are not   collapsed.
   This line uses    many    consecutive spaces    in many places; they are all collapsed.

The beauty of this solution is that you don't need to use any code in your Markdown document (in HTML you must use `&nbsp;`).

#### How to introduce a non-breaking space?

- In macOS, you need to press    <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- In Windows, sometimes work    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
- In many commercial software    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

#### Solution to the question example

**Main Topic**

**Subtopic1**
        Some Points for subtopic1
        Some Points for subtopic1
        Some Points for subtopic1

**Subtopic2**

**Subtopic3**
        Some Points for subtopic3
        Some Points for subtopic3
        Some Points for subtopic3

**Warning**
Copy and paste the previous example could not work because sometimes the system change non-breaking spaces to normal spaces in a copy-paste operation :‑(.

Answer (score 10):

In short, no, unless nested in a list.

In Markdown, code blocks are designated by indentation. Markdown provides no way to enable/disable that feature. Therefore, by design, you cannot have your (non-code-block) content indented.

Of course, there is one exception. Nested list items need to be indented. So, if your content is in a list and at least the first level is not indented, then, yes, this is possible:

```
* Main Topic
    * Subtopic1

        Some Points for subtopic1

    * Subtopic2

        Some Points for subtopic2
```

First, notice that the first line is a list item (`* Main Topic`). Then all the nested items are indented at least one level. The final level are not list items (although they could be) as a list item can contain paragraphs. However, all other levels **must** be list items as only list items can contain other nested levels.

The above will render as follows:

> - Main Topic
>
>   - Subtopic1
>
>     Some Points for subtopic1
>   - Subtopic2
>
>     Some Points for subtopic2

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work for me, in Inkdrop which is a note-taking app using markdown syntax.