# Markdown Text Alignment in Hexo Blog

Tags: html, css, markdown

I'm trying to build my personal blog with Hexo, which uses Markdown to write blog. When writing my About page, I want to use Tab to make the alignment looks better, I want the alignment to be like this:

[image]

Without tabs, the alignment looks like this:

[image]

Here's what I tried:

- Use `&nbsp;` or `&emsp;`, but to align the text, I have to repeat the character a lot of times, and the number of character used have to be calculated precisely
- Use [non-breaking spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023013/tab-space-in-markdown) by typing `option + space` on my Mac, but it doesn't seems to help, there was no indent at all
- Use HTML to write table, it could align the text, but the text have dark background, which looks not so good on the blog

I wonder is there any way to create the previously mentioned text alignment in Markdown or use HTML? I would be appreciated if you could kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, thanks Xinke Wu and [this issue](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1692).

```
{% raw %}
<div style="width:250px; height:auto; float:left; display:inline"><b>Birthday</b>:</div> 
<div>April 30, 1998</div>
{% endraw %}
```

The `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` tag would make it possible to insert a piece of HTML in a Markdown file in Hexo.