# Oracle AWR units of db time per sec (WORKLOAD REPOSITORY COMPARE PERIOD REPORT)

Tags: oracle, performance, awr

I'm getting WORKLOAD REPOSITORY COMPARE PERIOD REPORT that says

```
Load Profile 

1st per sec  
DB time:    1.3
```

I'm confused, Db time should be in time units, doesn't it?

---

BELOW are context and history of what's I've researched about AWRs and how I came to the answer I posted eventually.

I have ARW report that says

```
Elapsed Time (min)  DB time (min)  
60                  80
```

That I read e.g. here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:229943800346471782 it's explained how DB time can exceed elapsed time. And Db time is time, it's measured in time units (min = minute?), so far so good.

Then Load Profile says:

```
1st per sec  
DB time:    1.3
```

If DB time is 80 minutes in 60 minutes, than per sec by math should be 80/60/60, where that division by 60 to get per second go?

EDIT: my guess now as the question have been posted that this metric is in seconds, although units are not mentioned in AWR and I could not find about it in web by `awr db time in sec` search. Please provide link where it's confimed for sure (if it is so).

EDIT 2: `WORKLOAD REPOSITORY report` says, `DB Time(s): per sec` in `Load profile` section, where as `WORKLOAD REPOSITORY COMPARE PERIOD REPORT` just says `Db time per sec`. So now with like 99% assurance I can guess compare report uses same units, it's still not 100% sure fact. I actually get the reports via automated system, so cannot be sure they not mangled along the way...

P.S. by the way, I tried to do pretty formating of output, wanting to insert tabs, but could not find how, e,g. here [Tab space in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023013/tab-space-in-markdown) it says for similar it's not possible in markdown. Please add in comment if it can be done on stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Note that 80/60 = 1.3 is unitless (minute / minute); no need to convert from minutes to seconds.

Comment: @Marmite Bomber, The question was about units in compare AWR, Db time should be time units, doesn't it?

Comment: Then please edit the question such as *What unit has the DB Time in AWR Report?* and remove the not relevant parts. Now it is hard to answer.

Comment: @Marmite Bomber, edited, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that due to lots of info to fit on one line of compare AWR developers of the report decided to skip `(s):` which is present on the same place in ordinary (not compare) AWR.

I've looked at `WORKLOAD REPOSITORY report`, it says: `DB Time(s): per sec` 1.4 in `Load profile` section, where as `WORKLOAD REPOSITORY COMPARE PERIOD REPORT` just says `Db time per sec` and states 2nd 1.4. So now with like 99% assurance I can guess compare report uses same units - seconds for per seconds metric. Not 100% sure, but what are things we are 100% sure anyway?