# How to add Tab spaces in Git Readme between two sentences?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I have two sentences that I like to keep side by side. I am unable to add tab space between them using "\t" like word doc. When I give a long space it previews as just 1 space. Hence, please lmk how to add tab spaces in github readme.

exameple:

"This is a ball"       "\t"         "This is a bat".

Comment: `&nbsp;` for each literal space you want to add should work in most Markdown implementations. https://steemit.com/markdown/@jamesanto/how-to-add-multiple-spaces-between-texts-in-markdown

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to align some text?  Create a table?  Something else?  There may be a way to better accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 16):

I think this link will be helpfull for you.
Please go throught the answer and you will find what you needed i hope.

Type `&nbsp;` to add a single space.
Type `&ensp;` to add 2 spaces.
Type `&emsp;` to add 4 spaces.
You can use non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) 4 times to insert a tab.

[Tab space in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023013/tab-space-in-markdown)